# OpenCart - Custom product field in admin panel

Tags: field, opencart, admin, product, panel

So...

I want to add a field for product's (add/edit) page in admin panel where will be a checkbox or a Boolean option (yes/no) which will be displaying to the product's front page. I know how to do the last part, and where "last part" I mean how to display it on the product page but I have no clue how I could add another field to the products admin add/edit page.

OpenCart version: 3.0.2

I would be grateful if you guys help me out to solve that :) 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Admin panel:
 1. Catalog -> Options - to create new product options
 2. Catalog -> Products -> Edit -> Option(tab) - assign created before option to currently editing product